# How to change font settings in steam for Main Category text?

Tags: steam, pc

I am working on changing some of the fonts and font sizes in the steam client with a skin editing the steam.styles file. However, some of the categories are quite confusing and hard to find. I am looking for the category that specifies the text styles of the Store, Library, Community etc. text at the top.

Does anyone know what category these lie under, or possibly know of some sort of tool to help me find what categories these objects fall under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [discussion on Steam regarding the changing of fonts](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/pixelvisionskin/discussions/0/613937306593660256/), the section you're after is the Steam Navigation Bar, which comprises of the Store, Library, Community, Profile links across the top of the Steam client.

The section name as it appears in the style should be called `CUINavButton`.